# .h: No such file or directory NDK Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin

Hi Ivgot  set the gnu make buldier Cros GCC, and javah create by cygwin, . hedaer files. 
And I have the .h and .cpp in the same jni direcotry:  I dont understand by this error:

```
        make all 
     Building file: ../jni/com_jp_algi_CoreC.cpp
  Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
     g++ -I"C:\android-ndk-r5c\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include" -O0 -g3 -           Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"jni/com_jp_algi_CoreC.d" -                MT"jni/com_jp_algi_CoreC.d" -o "jni/com_jp_algi_CoreC.o" "../jni/com_jp_algi_CoreC.cpp"
         ../jni/com_jp_algi_CoreC.cpp:2:31: fatal error: com_jp_algi_CoreC.h: No such            file or        directory
   jni/subdir.mk:18: recipe for target `jni/com_jp_algi_CoreC.o' failed
   compilation terminated.
    make: *** [jni/com_jp_algi_CoreC.o] Error 1
```

Android buldier works but ...Syas this error no implementaion....of the antive. and I must to use I thnik external make, when I create .h by javah in cygwin...maybe i convert this java project in to C++-add nature..maybe there will be problem?

Ivgot this .mk:

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

   include $(CLEAR_VARS)

  LOCAL_MODULE    := com_jp_algi_CoreC
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_jp_algi_CoreC.cpp

   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

.cpp:

```
 #include <com_jp_algi_CoreC.h>
    /* Header for class com_jp_algi_CoreC */


  extern "C" {

  JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_jp_algi_CoreC_vector
 (JNIEnv *env, jobject clazz, jfloatArray input){
jfloat* flt1=NULL ;
jsize size = env->GetArrayLength(input);
jint i;
// check if array size >0 and wedont cause exception


// allocate buffer for array and get data from Java array
flt1  = new jfloat[size];
env->GetFloatArrayRegion(input,0,size,flt1);
// exception check. Always use exception check

// do stuff to the array

for (i = 0 ; i < size; i++){
    flt1[i] = 1;
}



// vector(flt1);
// set result to Java array and delete buffer. And exception check of course
env->SetFloatArrayRegion(input,0,size,flt1);
delete[] flt1;

// All is ok

  }


 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_jp_algi_CoreC_vector2
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jfloatArray, jobjectArray);


   }
```

.h:
          /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
          #include 
         /* Header for class com_jp_algi_CoreC */

```
      #ifndef _Included_com_jp_algi_CoreC
      #define _Included_com_jp_algi_CoreC
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
       #endif
    /*
  * Class:     com_jp_algi_CoreC
 * Method:    vector
 * Signature: ([F)V
    */
  JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_jp_algi_CoreC_vector
    (JNIEnv *, jobject, jfloatArray);

      /*
     * Class:     com_jp_algi_CoreC
   * Method:    vector2
    * Signature: ([F[[F)V
        */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_jp_algi_CoreC_vector2
   (JNIEnv *, jobject, jfloatArray, jobjectArray);

   #ifdef __cplusplus
  }
 #endif
    #endif
```

and this CoreC class:

```
   package com.jp.algi;

  public class CoreC {
        static {
    System.loadLibrary("com_jp_algi_CoreC");
    }

public native void vector(float[] input);

public native void vector2(float[] input, float[][] input2);

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the "com_jp_algi_CoreC.h" file is included inside the "com_jp_algi_CoreC.cpp" file?

Does your Android.mk file look like this?

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := module_name
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_jp_algi_CoreC.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Is your directory structure inside the Android project like this?

```
jni/
├── Android.mk
├── com_jp_algi_CoreC.h
├── com_jp_algi_CoreC.cpp
```

Also try to run **ndk-build** from the root of the project instead of Eclipse and see if there is any difference.

EDIT: Using your code I've created a test Android application and compiled the native code with 
**ndk-build** and it all works fine.

Comment: When i try  to ndku-build instead of my project in cygwin: bash: command not found

Comment: Can you update your question with the contents of the files: com_jp_algi_CoreC.h com_jp_algi_CoreC.cpp and Android.mk ? Are you sure the name of the file com_jp_algi_CoreC.cpp is the same as the one defined in LOCAL_SRC_FILES?

Answer (score 0):

Your NDK is quite old. There are many improvements and bug fixes in the new version. The latest today is r8d, and it works on Windows without cygwin.

Regarding your code, you don't need that `#include` statement at all, if you simply remove the first line of your .cpp file, it will compile and link correctly.